# Why is `python` and `python3` launching different versions of python in my venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

I'm trying to run some scripts to do some tasks on Windows 10 and I noticed this behavior with python

I created a virtual environment to install the required python packages. After activating the virtual environment I noticed that `python` would launch the correct python of the venv but `python3` would launch a completely different one (without any of the packages installed on the venv).

Is there anything I can do so that both `python` and `python3` both point to the venv?

Screenshot to show behavior
[image]
Tried looking at the Path but I do not know what to change here

Comment: the OS looks for the first match to the command on its path. It's as simple as that. The virtual environment has "python.exe" in its scripts folder, which is first on the path in an activated venv. But it doesn't have python3 so the OS does its job and keeps checking the path, as it must.

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It is explained in this long answer how `cmd.exe` searches for programs/scripts of which file name is specified without path and without file extension. There can be used also `where python` and `where python3` to see what is found first as `%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe` searches similar to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: `python3.exe` is usually a symbolic link which links to a different *Python* executable than `python.exe` found by `cmd.exe` or `where.exe` (or `powershell.exe`, `cscript.exe`, `wscript.exe`, ...).

Comment: After running `where python` and `where python3` I can see that the first python.exe found is the one in my venv and python3.exe is located in a different path. After some more searching I found that I can use the `mklink` to create a symlink for to my python.exe in the venv, and now both `python3` works as I want.
Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

When you download Python from the [python.org](https://www.python.org/), it is installed in a different location compared to when you download it from the Microsoft Store.
Therefore, the command used to execute them will be different.

When using 'python', the version downloaded from the website will be used, whereas when using 'python3', the version from the Microsoft Store will be used.